# Does Oracle 11g support CREATE ASSERTION?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

When I tried to write the following statement:

```
CREATE ASSERTION ir_collaboration
CHECK(NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT ngo, id_employee, COUNT(*)
  FROM collaboration
  GROUP BY ngo, id_employee
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
  )
);
```

I got

> Error SQL: ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command

Do I get this error message because it is valid in SQL-92 standard but Oracle 11g does not support it?

Comment: You could easily check the Oracle SQL Reference manual, at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm

Comment: How BLEEDING RIDICULOUS is it to close a question about ASSERTIONs, asked in a DATABASE forum as being OFF-TOPIC ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm)

There is no `CREATE ASSERTION` in Oracle. RDBMS products do not necessarily implement all features in the SQL standards.

And to add to the above:

[Check Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52204)

> **Restrictions on Check Constraints**
>
> The condition of a check constraint can refer to any column in the
>   table, but it cannot refer to columns of other tables.
>
> **Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following constructs:**
>
> Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions

Comment: Actually there is **no** DBMS that supports assertions

Comment: Can't they be implemented via `TRIGGER`s? For example, if the `SUM` of a bank manger's loan book exceeds 1M€, then don't let them lend any more - would be relatively easy to implement in a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: @Vérace yes they can, at least in principle, but the example you provide betrays that you actually have very little idea of the intricate complexities to be taken into account.  For example, your example, with the very precise way you formulated it, does allow a manager's loan book to exceed 1M, and is in fact not enforceable not even as an ASSERTION.

Answer (score 0):

@Balazs Papp's answer is of course correct. Oracle has not implemented `CREATE ASSERTION` and no other major DBMS has.

The specific assertion though can be as easily implemented with a simple `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE collaboration 
  ADD CONSTRAINT ir_collaboration
    UNIQUE (ngo, id_employee) ;
```

No two rows with same `ngo` and same `id_employee` will be allowed in the table and that's what the assertion would prevent, too.